# SQL Server : script schema & data, need to adjust 'GO' spacing

Tags: sql-server

I've got a 60GB `.sql` file that was created via script (schema & data). I've tried to apply it against another DB (the 2 need to merge).

It continues to fail because MS put the `go` command every 100 lines. Apparently, given the embedded files in the tables, this is causing the process to timeout and fail.

I have confirmed this by manually adding some 'go' commands in the block that's causing the first stoppage. However, this just leads to another block that won't process.

If I could re-script the DB, but specify that a 'go' command was closer than every 100 lines I would be in good shape.

Is this a configurable option in SSMS 2017? Maybe in registry somewhere?

Comment: `It continues to fail because MS put the go command every 100 lines`.Can you please elaborate,other statements will even succeed because of this batch seperator

Comment: Sorry I was unclear... it was very late.  I need the 'go' command more often than every 100 rows. Apparently 100 rows is too much to insert and the process fails. I manually edited a section and added a 'go' command every 10 lines and this solved the problem. Now I need an automated way to 1)recreate the script with the 'go' every 10 lines or 2)edit the existing one.